# How to put 3-D scattered data in cells in Python?

Tags: python, cells, networkx

I've got 3 list of some scattered data in the 3-D space, let's say for instance:

X, Y, Z

each one representing coordinates, which range within some definite intervals, and containing N data. But my problems is to find a way to put data into cells of definite size which should not overlap each other. So that I have to apply Networkx to create a complex network depending on the order of appearance of data from one cell to another.

Hope you can help me please to find a tool or something else which I can use.